# MySQL Query not getting accurate output

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three categories & subcategories in table.
Category (adventure, rejuvenation, gourmet) AND sub_category(air, balloon etc.)

Now I am firing below query

```
select * from products where sub_category Like '%Air%' or 
sub_category Like '%Land%' and category = 'adventure' 
and type = 'experience' and status = 'active'
```

Now problem is it is also getting rows where category = Rejuvenation. Hence it should only get result where category = adventure

Comment: Note also that `'%...'` cannot use an index, so if there's any way you can avoid that, so much the better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use brackets arround the or Statements:

```
select * from products where (sub_category Like '%Air%' or 
sub_category Like '%Land%' )and category = 'adventure' 
and type = 'experience' and status = 'active'
```

Answer (score 0):

AND has priority over OR. That's why your query returns everything, that has a sub category like Air. You should update your query like this:

```
select * from products where (sub_category Like '%Air%' or 
sub_category Like '%Land%') and category = 'adventure' 
and type = 'experience' and status = 'active'
```